# Replacing string from sentence using Regex expressions

Tags: php, regex

I want to make a script that finds strings with this format `{Hello|Hi|Hey}` from different sentences using `{([\w|]+)}` and then uses `(?<=[{|])\w+(?=[|}])` to get the individual words and randomly selects one of the words and replaces the starting with it.

Do I have to use a loop to find each formatted string and then put the individual words in an array and count values in the array and use rand function to get random value and replace the string with it? Which functions do I have to use?

Comment: You should try to make a solution first and then come and ask if you have any specific difficulties doing so.

Comment: Use `preg_replace_callback`

Answer (score 1):

You dont need twice preg_match;

this is maybe what you are asking:

```
<?php

$a = '{Hello|Hi|Hey}';

preg_match ( '{([\w|]+)}',$a,$array );

$items = explode("|",  $array[0]);
echo $items[rand(0, count($items) - 1)]  ;
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me an idea of how I supposed to code it!